# Can't finish registering because I need a phone number

Tags: gmail

What should I do if I don't have a phone number for gmail? There is nothing written for 'don't have a phone number' and I don't want to use anyone else's because they might use it for their account and also they might be able to see my messages, darn gmail for being new, when I made it before i didn't need a phone number, and I don't want to use my old one because I want 2 separate ones.

Comment: This is not a mandatory field. You can leave blank that field and just verify that you are not robot. It should work.

Comment: Just now I created an email with your name without using any phone number or alternate email id. majabeen27@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Mobile phone is **not** a mandatory field.

[image]